# Javascript: For loop seems to split function before executing code?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm trying to use the **Google Maps v3 API** to calculate the distance between several postcodes. I have a starting postcode and 5 destination postcodes, so it’s a case of locating the nearest destination from the starting point. I'm passing the postcode info to the web page via query string on the URL.

Example of the URL:  **`/HTML/319976/try-map.html?siteloc=NG4 3AA United Kingdom&postcode1=E13 8HL United Kingdom&postcode2=LE5 0HJ United Kingdom&postcode3=G43 1PX United Kingdom&postcode4=DE22 3LR United Kingdom&postcode5=LS9 9NE United Kingdom`**

So, here's the **magic bit**, for which most of the part works. ***Ignore the numerous alerts***, they're just for debugging. The bit that doesn't seem to work as I need it to is the `directionsService`.route part highlighted below.

The problem I'm having is when `calcRoute()` is called, as you can see most of the function is wrapped inside a `for loop` so I can cycle through the function for each postcode in the queryParms array, but the `directionsService.route` method isn't executed as part of the rest of the function; the `for loop` seems to go through the rest of the function the appropriate number of times until `getNearest()` is called, and then the `directionsService.route` method is called afterwards the same number of times as the for loop dictated, so it's as if the function is split into two and the `for loop` goes through each part separately. Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

```
<script>

    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var locations = new Array();
    var queryParms = new Array();
    var start;
    var end;

    function initialize() {
    alert("initialize");
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var home = new google.maps.LatLng(52.966314, -1.08052);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: home
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      getQueryVars();
    }

    function getQueryVars() {
    alert("getQueryVars");
      var pair;
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1); 
      var vars = query.split("&"); 
    alert("vars = " + vars);
      for (i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] != "siteloc") { 
          queryParms.push(pair[1]);
    alert("queryParms = " + queryParms);
        } else {
            start = pair[1];
            alert("start = " + start);
            }
        }
      calcRoute(); 
    }

    function calcRoute() {
      for (j=0;j<queryParms.length;j++) {
        end = queryParms[j];
        alert("end (queryParms[j]) = " + end);

    //waypoints not used for this postcode distance search but left in for future use if needed
        var waypts = [];
        var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
          if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
            waypts.push({
              location:checkboxArray[i].value,
              stopover:true});
        }
      }
    alert("creating request");
        request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
    alert(request);
        **directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    alert("status ok");
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
            numericOutput = route.legs[i].distance.text.replace(/ km/g,"");
    alert(numericOutput);
            locations.push({
              loc:end, 
              distance:numericOutput});
    alert(locations);
          }
        });**
      }
      if (j == queryParms.length) {
          getNearest();
      }
    }

    function getNearest()
    {
    alert("getNearest");
        locations.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.val - b.val; });
        document.getElementById("output").value = locations[0];
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Welsome to stackoverflow. Please learn to format your posts!

Comment: Perhaps misspelling a comment criticizing semantics wasn't the best idea. @epascarello

Comment: Eeeek trying my best!

Comment: You should try in terms of learning how to ask a question. Click on edit. You can see how the modified code is made to look different. Learn the syntax from each question you visit by clicking on edit. Just check out how the different **symbols** work to improve the formatting of the question.

Comment: Two points: #1: Learn to use `console.log` for debugging rather than alerts. #2: directionsService.route looks like it's asynchronous and that is your problem.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) seems to confirm that your call to the Google API is asynchronous: `Accessing the Directions service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the request.`

Comment: So what actually is the problem? Your calls are asynchronous and you are passing a callback function. Is there an error here?

Comment: An `URL` cannot contain space.

Comment: @Rajesh - thank you, i will work on the formatting of my questions, and the URL doesn't really have spaces, it's my bad formatting

Comment: @Matt Burland - thank you for the info, it's probably no surprise that I'm pretty new to coding, but the issue ultimately is that I get an error msg: "Unable to get property 'distance' of undefined or null reference" once the directionsService.route is called.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `directionsService.route` issues an AJAX call, which is why you have to pass a callback function. However, since you're issuing the call inside a `for` loop **and** attempting to use the counter variable `i` inside the callback function's body, you'll run into issues because `i` won't retain the value for that iteration when the callback function executes; if all of the AJAX requests complete after the loop (which is likely) then `i` will be the value for the last iteration of the loop in each of them.

You'll need to create a closure to preserve its value, like so:

```
(function(i) {
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            alert("status ok");
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
            numericOutput = route.legs[i].distance.text.replace(/ km/g, "");
            alert(numericOutput);
            locations.push({
                loc : end,
                distance : numericOutput
            });
            alert(locations);
        }
    });
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `directionsService.route` method is asynchronous, hence the second parameter is a function which will execute when the AJAX call is complete.

But you call `GetNearest()` outside of this callback, so when the `for` loop is at it's last iteration, `GetNearest()` will be called before all the callbacks have gotten a chance to execute.

Try moving the if statement `if (j == queryParms.length) {...}` inside the callback.